# How to paste copied character in ex mode?

Tags: ex-mode, paste

Pressing `yl` I can copy the character where cursor locates. Now I press `:` to enter into last line mode, I enter `%s/`. Now I want to paste the character copied by `yl`. How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>"</kbd> to insert the contents of the default register into the Ex command line. The default register is where what you just yanked will be.

See [`:help c_CTRL-R`](https://vimhelp.org/cmdline.txt.html#c_CTRL-R) for details.

Comment: Long way: open up the command window (ctrl-f) and p it in normal mode